# Como eu interromper o código caso uma condição não seja cumprida

Tags: python, condição

Estou tendo problema para descobrir como evitar que o resto do código seja executado caso uma condição if não seja cumprida.

```
n1 = int(input('Insira o primeiro número: '))
n2 = int(input('Insira o segundo número: '))
n3 = int(input('Insira o terceiro número: '))
if n1 == n2 or n1 == n3 or n2 == n3:
    print('Não são permitidos valores iguais!')
# Verificando quem é maior
if n1 > n2 and n1 > n3:
    print('O maior número é: {}'.format(n1))
elif n2 > n1 and n2 > n3:
    print('O maior número é: {}'.format(n2))
else:
    print('O maior número é: {}'.format(n3))
# Verificando quem é menor
if n1 < n2 and n1 < n3:
    print('O menor número é: {}'.format(n1))
elif n2 < n1 and n2 < n3:
    print('O menor valor é: {}'.format(n2))
else:
    print('O menor valor é: {}'.format(n3))
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Precisa obrigatoriamente ter esse monte de `if`/`elif`? Porque daria para ser apenas `if n1 == n2 == n3: print('não pode ter valores iguais') else: menor, _, maior = sorted([n1, n2, n3]) (imprime maior e menor)`

Answer (score 0):

Use um `else` para parar a execução caso entre no primeiro `if` de erro

```
n1 = int(input('Insira o primeiro número: '))
n2 = int(input('Insira o segundo número: '))
n3 = int(input('Insira o terceiro número: '))
if n1 == n2 or n1 == n3 or n2 == n3:
    print('Não são permitidos valores iguais!')
else: //para parar parar a execução
    # Verificando quem é maior
    if n1 > n2 and n1 > n3:
        print('O maior número é: {}'.format(n1))
    elif n2 > n1 and n2 > n3:
        print('O maior número é: {}'.format(n2))
    else:
        print('O maior número é: {}'.format(n3))
    # Verificando quem é menor
    if n1 < n2 and n1 < n3:
        print('O menor número é: {}'.format(n1))
    elif n2 < n1 and n2 < n3:
        print('O menor valor é: {}'.format(n2))
    else:
        print('O menor valor é: {}'.format(n3))
```